# How to check ALL multi values of dictionary as a condition for pd.dataframe in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, string, list

I have a dictionary:

```
variables = {
        "key1": ["v1"],
        "key2": ["v2","v3"],
        "key3": ["v4","v5"],          
}
```

and a dataframe: report_list which has multi columns including col1.

I have made something successfully if col1 match ANY of values group by key then generate a finalList. (If someone could check it will be great)

```
for variable_key in variables: 
 for x in variables[variable_key]:
     tempList = report_list.loc[(report_list[col1].str.contains(x))]
     finalList = finalList.append(tempList)
     finalList = finalList[0:0]
```

But I am stuck in if col1 match ALL of values group by key then be appended into a finalList.
E.g. the cell value in col1 contains string v1 or (v2 and v3) or (v4 and v5) so the row will be appended into the final list.

Thank for any help.

Comment: can you post  `report_list.head()` and your expected output from it?

Comment: I expected to check the cell value of one column to match ALL dictionary values group by dictionary key. so for key1, the row with the cell value of col1 will be appended into the finalList if the cell value contains v1. for key2, the row of cell value of col1 will be appended into the finalList if the cell value contains v2 AND v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the values in the dict to a list with `list(variables.values())` and filter whether an item in `col1` is in the list, then convert the filtered dataframe to list to get the desired output:

```
import pandas as pd

variables = {
        "key1": ["v1"],
        "key2": ["v2","v3"],
        "key3": ["v4","v5"],          
}

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [["v6"],["v2","v3"], ["v1"], ["v4", "v3"]]})

df[df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x in list(variables.values()))]['col1'].tolist()
```

output:

```
[['v2', 'v3'], ['v1']]
```

You can also check whether any of the items in a list in `col1` is in the dict using list comprehension:

```
df[df['col1'].apply(lambda x: any([i for i in x for sublist in list(variables.values()) if i in sublist]))]['col1'].tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['v2', 'v3'], ['v1'], ['v4', 'v3']]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my col1, they are all strings like "v2testv3" So it will match key2's value ["v2","v3"]

Comment: You can split the strings to make the code work: `df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.split('test')`

Comment: I can not use split. As the string would be all kinds of strings. Is there any way I could use str.contains() and with multiple substrings as condition.

Comment: Thanks I have come up with the solution.